# how to detect the visible of another jframe class

Tags: java, swing

let say

```
public class Dirchooser extends JFrame {
    protected String dir;
    ...
    private AbstractAction getGetDirAction() {
        if (getDirAction == null) {
            getDirAction = new AbstractAction("OK", null) {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                dir = dirPathTextField1.getText();
                setVisible(false);}};}
return getDirAction;}}
```

how can i detect the visible of Dirchooser and get the string dir using another class?
like

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            inst = new DirChooser();
            inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            inst.setVisible(true);}});
//if inst is not visible,

//sysout string dir which in inst
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure about what you wanted to know. But if you wanted to check if DirChooser is visible on the screen or not then you can use this inst.isShowing(); that can return a boolean. Moreover, to read variable from first class in second class, simply make an Object of the first class in the second Class and access the variable like System.out.println(firstClassObject.variableName). Hope that can help. Regards

Comment: @ProphesyAwaits : Why not write this as an answer?

Comment: @HarryJoy : okay sure, will do the same. Regards

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to check if `DirChooser` is visible on the screen or not, then you can use this `inst.isShowing();` that can return a `boolean`.

Moreover, to read variable from first class in second class, simply make a reference to an object of the first class in the second class and access the variable (public or protected; inside the same package or from a super class) like `System.out.println(firstClassObject.variableName`. Hope that can help. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use a listener, and have DirChooser call you back when it's finished. That's the Java way of doing it, see "Design Patterns".

Answer (score 1):

```
..
public class Dirchooser extends JFrame {
..
```

1st, change that to..

```
public class DirChooser extends JPanel {
```

Which changes the frame to a panel, and gives the class name correct case.  Then, put that panel in a modal [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html).

Add a method to `DirChooser` along the lines of `getDirPath()` and call that method the code line after the call to `modalDialog.setVisible(true)`.